spring validation: handling validation on services
I'd like to get ``ConstraintViolationException` and transform them into custom bussiness errors into service layer.
I mean, my code:
@Component
@Validated
@Slf4j
public class DummyService {

  public Either<String,DummyError> dummyMethod(@NotNull String name) {
    try {
      return Either.left("Hello, " + name + "!");
    } catch (ConstraintViolationException e) {
      log.atError().setCause(e).setMessage("Error in dummyMethod").log();
      return Either.right(DummyError.fromConstraintViolationException(e));
    }
  }

}

